# React.js - Cant Display DataRows to TBody

Tags: reactjs

It writes to the document but can't display in the screen. I tried a lot of solution but didn't fix this problem. I'm trying to get data from the API and show on the Table. I share the render() function in my component class. You can view here.

```
render() {
    let data = this.state.data, countries = Object.keys(data);
    let dataArray = countries.map(country => data[country].All);

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Country Name</th>
              <th>Capital City</th>
              <th>Continent</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Abbreviation</th>
              <th>Confirmed Patients</th>
              <th>Death Patients</th>
              <th>Population</th>
              <th>Life Expectancy</th>
              <th>Updated Time</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              this.state.dataIsNull === false ? dataArray.map((tempData,
                index) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={"row" + index}>
                    <td>{dataArray.indexOf(tempData)}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.country}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.capital_city}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.continent}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.location}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.abbreviation}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.confirmed}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.deaths}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.population}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.life_expectancy}</td>
                    <td>{tempData.updated}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              }) : <tr><td>Empty</td></tr>
            } 
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: NOTE: It doesn't give any error.

Comment: try to see in  console.log(tempData)

Comment: You can view `console.log(tempData)` code's output. [Output Console](https://imgur.com/a/oww86XS) @HuzaifaQidwai

Comment: How are you sure it writes to the document but doesn't print on the screen? Explain this by editing the question, providing some more images

Comment: @Ergis, I explain to [like this](https://imgur.com/a/LskS95r).